# How to prevent the same option/value from being selected multiple times in a switch statement

Tags: c++

I'm creating a menu using C++ for a project. On a specific part of my project I am using a switch statement to allow the user to pick between different options in that menu. The issue is that currently they are allowed to choose the same option multiple times. Since each option has a specific value it adds on the value of that option the same number of times that the user chooses the option. I want to limit the amount of times the user can choose any option to a single time.

EDIT: I am not allowed to use arrays for this project.

```
void additionalOptionsMenu();

const double VIEW = 50.00;
const double JACUZZI = 40.00;
const double BREAKFAST = 15.00;
const double BED = 12.00;
const double WIFI = 9.00;

int main()
{

    double additionalOptions = 0.00;
    int subChoice;


    do{

           additionalOptionsMenu();

    cin >> subChoice;

        switch (subChoice){

            case 1:
                additionalOptions += VIEW;
                break;
            case 2:
                additionalOptions += JACUZZI;
                break;
            case 3:
                additionalOptions += BREAKFAST;
                break;
            case 4:
                additionalOptions += BED;
                break;
            case 5:
                additionalOptions += WIFI;
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            default:
                cout << "ERROR";
                break;


        }
        }while (subChoice != 6);

        cout << additionalOptions; 
//Displays the final value of additionalOptions

    return 0;
}


void additionalOptionsMenu()
{
    cout << "\n1. View: $50.00\n"
         << "\n2. Jacuzzi: $40.00\n"
         << "\n3. Breakfast: $15.00\n"
         << "\n4. Extra Bed: $12.00\n"
         << "\n5. Internet Access: $9.00\n"
         << "\n6. Previous Menu\n";
}
```

Comment: Right, so you have to figure out some other way to represent your user's options.  `std::unordered_set` comes to mind.

Comment: No arrays...Cool. Fire your teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to have an array of bools that you keep track of what the user has already chosen:

```
void additionalOptionsMenu();

const double VIEW = 50.0;
const double JACUZZI = 40.0;
const double BREAKFAST = 15.0;
const double BED = 12.0;
const double WIFI = 9.0;

enum AmenitysOption {
    , AMENITY_NONE
    , AMENITY_VIEW
    , AMENITY_JACUZZI
    , AMENITY_BREAKFAST
    , AMENITY_BED
    , AMENITY_WIFI
    , AMENITY_MAX
};

bool amenityOptions[AMENITY_MAX] = {};

int main()
{

    double additionalOptions = 0.0;
    int subChoice;
    do {
        additionalOptionsMenu();
        cin >> subChoice;
        if(amenityOptions[subChoice]) {
            cout << "\nYou've already picked that option.\n";
            continue;
        }
        switch (subChoice) {
            case AMENITY_NONE:
                break;
            case AMENITY_VIEW:
                additionalOptions += VIEW;
                amenityOptions[AMENITY_VIEW] = true;
                break;
            case AMENITY_JACUZZI:
                additionalOptions += JACUZZI;
                amenityOptions[AMENITY_JACUZZI] = true;
                break;
            case AMENITY_BREAKFAST:
                additionalOptions += BREAKFAST;
                amenityOptions[AMENITY_BREAKFAST] = true;
                break;
            case AMENITY_BED:
                additionalOptions += BED;
                amenityOptions[AMENITY_BED] = true;
                break;
            case AMENITY_WIFI:
                additionalOptions += WIFI;
                amenityOptions[AMENITY_WIFI] = true;
                break;
            case AMENITY_MAX:
                break;
            default:
                cout << "\nERROR";
                break;
        }
    } while (subChoice < AMENITY_MAX);

    cout << additionalOptions; 
    //Displays the final value of additionalOptions
    return 0;
}


void additionalOptionsMenu()
{
    cout << "\n1. View: $50.00\n"
         << "\n2. Jacuzzi: $40.00\n"
         << "\n3. Breakfast: $15.00\n"
         << "\n4. Extra Bed: $12.00\n"
         << "\n5. Internet Access: $9.00\n"
         << "\n6. Previous Menu\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to find that functionality in a base switch case. Adding that functionality to the switch statement using variables to check if options have been used would work. Do this by adding an if statement surrounding the += lines of code.

However, it might make your life easier in the long run to use a structure other than a switch case.